# Qt, QGraphicsView и QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

Осваиваюсь с разработкой **GUI** в **Qt**, возник ряд вопросов по работе двух вещей: **QGraphicsView** и **QGraphicsScene**.

1) Как на **Qt** реализуются огромные сцены?

Под огромными сценами я подразумеваю сотни тысяч и миллионы объектов. В основном - это точки, линии и надписи.

Например, мне необходимо отобразить график сигнала датчика, за один месяц. Это **> 2 600 000** точек (не менее 1 точки на каждую секунду месяца). Вместе с точками нужно отображать координатную сетку и некоторые надписи.

Первый прототип сделал *в лоб* - нарисовал сетку, которая содержит миллион линий по оси x. Добавил в сцену все точки графика. Производительность такого деревянного решения меня впечатлила, но все же хочется сделать график пошустрее, чтобы не было зависаний при прокрутке.

2) Вопрос вот в чем - нужно ли создавать сцену лишь из тех точек и линий, которые попадают в область просмотра? Или как это вообще делается?

Безусловно, сцена, содержащая пару тысяч объектов вместо миллионов, - будет работать на порядки быстрее, но... Ручная выборка точек, учет области просмотра и постоянное перевыделение памяти - это все очень сомнительно.

3) Как **QGraphicsView** отображает содержимое сцены? Используется ли аппаратное ускорение (*OpenGL*, *DX* и пр.)? Может его нужно как-то включить? Я поискал в документации, но что-то не нашел.

4) Если мы отрисовываем множество однотипных объектов, например, черточек графика, то как этот процесс оптимизировать, чтобы не делать миллионы вызовов **scene->addline()**?

Я не знаю, как конкретно устроен вызов добавления линии, но практически уверен, что каждый раз вызывается **new**. Хотелось бы, чтобы график рисовался не несколько секунд...

Comment: Усреднять соседние точки в зависимости от масштаба - это не просто нормально, это разумно. Про использование OpenGL пишут в [документации](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/QGraphicsView.html#details)

Comment: Разве **Qt** сам не выполняет усреднение при выводе?

Comment: Он вынужден это делать (судя по [исходникам](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/graphicsview/qgraphicsscene.cpp.html#_ZN14QGraphicsScene6renderEP8QPainterRK6QRectFS4_N2Qt15AspectRatioModeE) - при каждой перерисовке) и результат такой работы вас не устраивает. Больше бы узнать о том, как вы просовываете туда данные и насколько график должен быть динамичен.

Comment: График не должен быть динамичен. Необходимо просто отрисовать линии сетки, подписи и точки самого графика. Единственная функция создаваемого просмотрщика - просто посмотреть график, ничего не меняя. Собственно, вот.

Comment: А вам действительно нужно разрешение до одной секунды при выводе графика?

Comment: 1/1000 секунды. Это не суть важно. В любом случае, на графике будут миллионы точек, и я пытаюсь понять, как это все оптимизировать, и нужно ли делать это в ручную.

Comment: Миллионы точек на графике длиной пусть даже 4000 пикселей - неоптимальный расход ресурсов. Я рисую через `QPainter` все и везде используется оптимизация, при которой точка не рендерится, если расстояние до нее от предыдущей точки меньше условных 0.75 пикселя

Comment: Так в моем случае тормоза происходят не из-за того, что в один пиксель рисуется много точек, нет. В большинстве ситуаций между двумя ближайшими точками будет значительное расстояние. Основная проблема в том, что сцена содержит очень много объектов. Как решается эта проблема? Создавать сцену только из тех элементов, которые влезают в область просмотра?

Comment: Плюс, смысла в костыльной ручной оптимизации отрисовки только далеких точек нет, потому что существует масштабирование.

Comment: Будет неплохо, если вы опишите свой юзкейс. Каков шаг масштабирования и максимальное/минимальное разрешение требуется для графика? Какие шаги прокрутки?

Comment: максимальное масштабирование - 1 пиксель на 1 мсекунду. Минимальное масштабирование - 1 пиксель на 1 секунду.

Comment: То есть можно попробовать подгружать полчаса слева-справа. Когда юзер скроллится до получаса - начинать в фоне подтягивать слеюующие полчаса, предыдущие - выгружать.

Comment: Да, это самое очевидное решение, но мне не нравится в этом случае, что придется пересоздавать сцену. Если бы я решал эту проблему на Open GL, то мог бы просто передавать на отрисовку точки +- 30 минут, а в Qt при использовании QGraphichsScene придется сперва создавать сцену, затем добавлять в нее примитивы, затем удалять старую. Да, сцена будет создаваться лишь при более-менее протяжном скролинге, но все равно, я думаю, что будут подтормаживания...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С вашего позволения не буду отвечать те вопросы, которые касаются внутренней архитектуры Qt, но могу посоветовать две оптимизации, которые повысят скорость рендеринга.

1. Насколько я понимаю, график добавляется как набор линий через циклический вызов `addLine`. Эти вызовы надо заменить на добавление линий в полигон и уже этот полигон добавлять на сцену. Код приблизительно следующий:

   ```
   QPolygon poly;
   QPainterPath path;
   for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++)
       poly.append(points[i]);
   path.addPolygon(polygon);
   scene.addPath(path);
   ```
2. Если сцена используется только для отрисовки, а никакое взаимодействие с объектами не требуется (ткнуть, выделить, переместить, etc) надо отключить индексацию, это существенно ускорит добавление объектов:

   ```
   scene.setItemIndexMethod(QGraphicsScene::NoIndex);
   ```

UPD:

Еще немного советов по оптимизации https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43826317/how-to-optimize-qgraphicsviews-performance

UDP2:

Результат выглядит следующим образом (на картинке миллион точек (общий размер графика видно по скроллбару внизу):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Странно, но даже простое отключение индексации - замедляет процесс отрисовки. А если к этому еще и добавить добавление линий в полигон и присоединение полигона к сцене, то все просто висит.

Comment: @Максим, отключение индексации увеличивает алгоритмическую сложность поиска до линейной и, опять же, как пишут в документации, рекомендуется лишь для статичных графиков.

Comment: Специально написал тестовый код, сначала происходит добавление линий, потом `QGraphicsView` отрисовывает сцену. Для случая с циклическим добавлением линий время добавления примерно в 12 раз больше, чем для полигона. Отрисовка в первом случае в несколько раз дольше, чем добавление, во втором почти мгновенная. Qt 5.11.1, MinGW x86. А вот индексация почти не повлияла на быстродействие.

Comment: Скролл для полигона почти мгновенный, для набора линий на один шаг скролла уходит в районе секунды. Надо разбираться, почему у вас добавление в полигон что-то замедлило

Comment: Мой график состоит из отдельных коротких линий, а не строится сплошной линией по точкам, может быть в этом проблема?

Comment: На выходе нужно предоставить просмотр графика, который построен из миллионов линий.

Comment: @Максим смотрите UPD2 в ответе

Comment: Спасибо, на сколько шустро у вас работает скроллинг для такого графика?

Comment: В релизной сборке лагов не заметно глазом, fps оценить не могу. На правах оффтопа замечу, что я долго экспериментировал со сценами и пришел к выводу, что проще, быстрее и надежнее написать свой компонент рендеринга с помощью `QPainter`, в нем можно применить все мыслимые оптимизации. Минус - время, затраченное на разработку.